# Rails 4 wicked pdf Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to use wicked pdf to render a html page as pdf.

mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

controller method

```
def invoice    
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "invoice"
      end
    end
end
```

wicked_pdf.rb

```
:exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

invoice.pdf.erb

```
<div id="test_pdf">
  test data
</div>
```

I have added the above codes and added the following gems to my project.

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

When I try to render the page, i get `Template is missing` error. If i rename `invoice.pdf.erb` to `invoice.html.erb` i can bypass the error, but i will be getting a html page instead of pdf.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the document of [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), you can use it like this. Its self explanatory. Don't forget to create "pdfs" directory

```
# or from your controller, using views & templates and all wicked_pdf options as normal  
  pdf = render_to_string pdf: "some_file_name", template: "templates/pdf.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8"

# then save to a file
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end

send_file save_path, :type=>'text/pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will be more than enough if you just want to render the pdf:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'file_name',
             template: 'example/pdf_view.pdf.erb',
             layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb'
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to save as pdf:

```
def save
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
                        render_to_string(
                          template: 'example/pdf_view.pdf.erb',
                          layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb'))
  send_data(pdf,
            filename: 'file_name.pdf',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            disposition: 'attachment')
end
```